# JUnit Test Output Truncated

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I am running JUnit tests in my build environment where I can only use logs to determine the cause of errors and am unable to step through the process via debugger. This makes clear error messages really important, but JUnit is truncating the comparison values very aggressively.

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<....com&content=2019022[5]&campaign=1> but was:<....com&content=2019022[6]&campaign=1>
```

This isn't much to go off of when the tests are running fine locally. How can I configure JUnit to spit out the entire comparison?

I am running the tests through `mvn test`.

Comment: You should configure `<trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>` (https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#trimStackTrace) apart from that can't you run the test locally? Having the same result? Maybe using assertj as alternative to JUnit assert...might be an improvement as well.

Comment: @khmarbaise I figured out the tests were written to work locally in my time zone but not in the build environments UTC timezone. That's where I was confused. This is helpful though and I'll add this now

Comment: Yeah timezone/time based tests are a horror...